# Shutdown is always a surprise?

Tags: 11.04

Each time I shut down my 11.04, I get a screen like the picture below before it actually turns off...

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Plymouth isn't  loading the graphical boot

Comment: What is plymouth ? How do I make it do what it is suppose to do?

Comment: Plymouth displays a graphical boot splash (or text) when your OS is loading, What's your laptop model? this maybe related to your graphics driver not supporting your graphics card thus Plymouth shows as text,.

Comment: My laptop is a DELL Latitude D830. Actually, plymouth seems to do his job but only partially at shutdown. For a few sec I get Ubuntu logo with moving dots, then I get what you can see on the pic above and just before shutdown Ubuntu logo comes back...

Comment: On my Dell the same occurs after updates have been added. I assumed it was due to delayed file writing etc at shutdown after package updates.

Comment: This question is similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/48695/the-terminal-is-shown-when-shutting-down-or-logging-out

Comment: Similar, yes... With no evident solution. How can I help?

Comment: I just updated to 11.10. Same problem here. Ubuntu showing what's underneath at shutdown... No solution so far...

Answer (score 3):

Uri Herrera is correct - Plymouth is not loading correctly most likely due to changes in your config by the graphics driver if you have recently updated it.

A good explanation of what Plymouth is and what it does can be found [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Plymouth)

If you would like to try to fix it you can install Super Boot Manager, [this link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/super-boot-manager-eases-burg-grub-plymouth-tweaking-pains/) to an OMGUbuntu article should give you all the info you need, you can install via PPA - remember when making system changes with any software you do so at your own risk so back up first!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, I never updated my graphics driver (it worked out of the box). I'll try the fix you suggest.

Comment: I just updated to 11.10. Same problem here. Ubuntu showing what's underneath at shutdown... No solution so far...